# How to distinguish that a scanned FM Radio channel is valid channel or invalid using android programming?

Tags: android, signal-processing

i have to find out the valid and invalid channels among the scanned channels. for example if 10 channels are scanned out of which 8 are properly playing and 2 are not the valid channels, only noise is audible then how can i decide it using android programming.let me know if you want any further detail.i am scanning it on a android phone.if there is any other solution like using digital signal processing, FFT etc than please suggest with proper links.